# Always send mail using default email set. Outlook Add in works until email message is cancelled

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to create an outlook add in wherein we have 2 email accounts and I would want to set the reply mail to the default mail set. Currently the sending email defaults to whichever account it was sent to. I have checked online and saw similar posts which works but once I close the email message the code does not set the default email that I chose anymore. Can you please help? Below is my code:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Xml.Linq;

using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace OutlookAddIn1{
         public partial class ThisAddIn
         {
            private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
            private Outlook.Accounts accounts;
            private Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
            private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
                inspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
            }


    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
            {
            mailItem =Inspector.CurrentItem;

                accounts = Application.Session.Accounts;
            if (mailItem != null)
                {
                      if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
                      {
                            foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
                {
                                String strname = "xxxx";

                                if (account.SmtpAddress.ToString().IndexOf(strname)>0)
                                {
                                    mailItem.SendUsingAccount =account;

                                }
                            }
                          }
             }

        }
         }
    }

     #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {


            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);


        }

        #endregion
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest waiting for the first [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869361.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event to access the Outlook item.

Anyway, to preserve changes made programmatically you need to save the item by using the [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866979.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the current folder or, if this is a new item, to the Outlook default folder for the item type.

Comment: Hello Eugene, Thanks for responding. Can you help share the code for it?

Comment: Hello Eugene, It worked!!! My reference was from https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/inspector-activate-event-under-vs2005-c.3206710/...Thanks a lot!!!